# Have been to/have gone to

Tags: grammaticality

Could you please see if I have the correct solution for this task:
"Write the sentence, using 'have (has) been'/'have (has) gone'. Don't forget about full stops.
Example 0. I haven't seen Kate for ages. (She/Paris/for a year)
Answer 0. She has gone to Paris for a year.

1. I have already come home. (I/Poland/for a year)

P.S. My try is:
1. I have been to Poland. I was there for a year.

(Can we incorporate the period "for a year" into the sentence "I have been to Poland."?)
So what's the right solution? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct. The verb GO has two past participles. *Gone* implies that the travellers are still in the place they went to. *Been* implies that they returned from their trip.

Because the first sentence stipulates that the speaker is now back, *been* is required here.

Comment: Yes, but can we include the duration of the stay (for a year) in this sentence? The task is to say it in one sentence, and I've used 2 sentences.

Comment: There's no problem stating durations with present perfect contructions. We can't say *when* in the past something happened with the present perfect, but that is slightly different and doesnt involve duration. So we wouldn't say *I have been in France last year*, for example.